# IOS custom pin is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to show the image instead of default red pin for source location and another image for destination location.

```
- (void) sourceMarker:(MKPlacemark * ) homeLoc {
MKAnnotationView *point = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

MKPointAnnotation *ml = point.annotation;

ml.coordinate = homeLoc.coordinate;

ml.title = @"Home";

point.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
point.canShowCallout = YES;

[self.mapView addAnnotation:ml];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Apple doc [Annotating Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html). One has to create custom annotation class, please refer the following code.

MyAnnotation.h

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;
NSString *type;

}

 @property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *type;
@end
```

MyAnnotation.m

```
@implementation MyAnnotation
  @synthesize coordinate;
  @synthesize title;
  @synthesize subtitle;
  @synthesize type;

@end
```

yourViewControll.m - Where you are showing the map.

Create the annotation and set the type property

```
MyAnnotation *Ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
offAnn.coordinate = offLocation.coordinate;
offAnn.title = @"My Office";
offAnn.type = @"Office";
[_mapView  removeAnnotation: offAnn];
[_mapView addAnnotation: offAnn];




- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation Called");
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    MyAnnotation *myAnn=(MyAnnotation *)annotation;

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyAnnotation"];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyAnnotation"];
        //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 4);

    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    if([myAnn.type  isEqual: @"Office"]) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"office.png"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *annotationViewID;
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
    annotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewID] ;
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"patientpin_l.png"];    
    // Add annotation image here        
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    return annotationView;

}
```